# Hit "enter" automatically every n seconds in python

Tags: python, time

I am calling an external program one a loop using a python script and in general everything works well. However, occasionally the program gets stuck performing a certain process. If I hit 'enter' then the program continues to run as desired.

Would it be possible to run a process in the background that will hit enter every `n` seconds (whether or not it the program is stuck)? This way I will the program will continue whether or not I am present to guide it.  This seems to go against my logic of how python works but I thought maybe there is some way around it.

Note: I will be running the python script in bash (ubuntu 15.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the external process like you have been doing but keep a pipe open to its stdin and periodically write a newline character to it.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from time import sleep

n = 10 # seconds

p = Popen(["external_program", "arg1", "arg2"], stdin=PIPE)
while <condition>:
    sleep(n)
    p.stdin.write(b'\n')
    p.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Could you elaborate how this would work? Doesn't the while loop only run after the external program is finished?

Comment: no, the external program runs asynchronously in the background

Comment: Add `p.stdin.flush()` or set `bufsize=0` explicitly. Use bytes literal for Python 3 compatibility: `b'\n'` or pass `universal_newlines=True` to enable text mode.

Comment: @JeffDror, if you used `communicate()` or `wait()` or another blocking invocation (`check_call()`, etc) that would be true, but not just creating a `Popen` object as done here.

Answer (score 1):

This would be difficult with Python, but [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) makes it very easy with [`Loop`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Loop.htm) and [`WinWaitActive`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm). The following script will start a loop that waits for a window titled "Calculator" to become active, then immediately sends <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and goes back to the beginning of the loop, waiting for the next Calculator window to appear. In effect, it closes the Calculator as soon as you start it.

```
Loop {
    WinWaitActive, Calculator
    Send !{F4}
}
```

Replace `Calculator` with the name of the error dialog window's title, and `!{F4}` with `{Enter}`:

```
Loop {
    WinWaitActive, Flagrant Error
    Send {Enter}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will be be running the script in Linux so I am not sure if autohotkey will work.